# How to Invoke spring kafkaListener method manually

Tags: spring-kafka

I have created a java class and method has @KafkaListener. But I want this method need to be invoked only when I click the button from UI.  When I click a button from UI, call goes to controller class and from controller class I want to invoke this class. How can do this?
I did not add any class level annotations.

```
public class MessageListener implements ConsumerSeekAware {

   
    private String topicName;
     
     private int partition;
     
     private long beginOffset;
     
     private long endOffset;
 
  
    public MessageListener(String topicName, int partition, long beginOffset, long endOffset) {
        super();
        this.topicName = topicName;
        this.partition = partition;
        this.beginOffset = beginOffset;
        this.endOffset = endOffset;
    }
 

    @KafkaListener(topics = "topicName", 
    concurrency = "20",
    clientIdPrefix = "clientId-Test",
    groupId = "clientId-group")
    public void handleMessage(final ConsumerRecord<Object, Object> consumerRecord) {
        System.out.println(consumerRecord);
    }
```

}

Option 2:

```
       public List<String> searchMessages(String topicName, int partitionNo, long beginOffset, long endOffset) {

    List<String> filteredMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    TopicPartition tp = new TopicPartition("topicName", partitionNo);
    Properties clusterOneProps = kafkaConsumerConfig.getConsumerProperties();
    KafkaConsumer<String, Object> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(clusterOneProps);

    try {
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("topicName"), new ConsumerRebalanceListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
            consumer.seek(tp, beginOffset); 
        }
    }); 
    Thread.sleep(100);    
    boolean flag = true;
    System.out.println("search started......from offset is "+beginOffset);
    while(flag) {   
    ConsumerRecords<String, Object> crs = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100L));
     for (ConsumerRecord<String, Object> record : crs) {
              // search criteria
               if(record.value().toString().contains("01111") && record.value().toString().contains("2021-11-06")) {
                   System.out.println("founddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd "+record.offset());
                   filteredMessages.add(record.value().toString());
               }
               if (record.offset() == endOffset) {
                   flag = false;
                   break;
               }
        }
     }
     System.out.println("doneeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        consumer.close();
    }
```

Comment: Just make this `MessageListener` as a bean. Inject it into your controller and call that method from your MVC side! Otherwise it is not clear if you'd like still get access to Kafka or not. Please, elaborate more what is your real goal. That `@KafkaListener` is really intended to be called by the Kafka listener container when records are pulled from the topic. What is the reason to call this method manually, not clear yet...

Comment: @ArtemBilan - My goal is "I have a topic with 20 partitions and has employee data. From UI search screen, I will pass multiple employee numbers,  Now I want to search all these partitions to find a particular employees data is there are not.  If it is matches then I want  put in a separate List  and download as file.  I know beginOffset and endOffest of each partitions in advance.  and looking for how efficiently/fast I can perform this.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to search all these partitions to find a particular employees data is there are not.

Then `@KafkaListener` is not for you. Looks like your requirement is on demand, when request is done. The `@KafkaListener` is thing by itself: it relies on constantly polling loop underneath. It fully does not depend on the end-user requests.

You need to think about creating a `KafkaConsumer` on the fly based on the data you have received in the WEB request. See `ConsumerFactory` instead for using it directly to create those consumers. Then you can call `poll()` on that consumer and close it in the end. This is already out of Spring for Apache Kafka scope though: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#connecting

Or... You can update to the latest `spring-kafka-2.8.0` and use `KafkaTemplate.receive()` API: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#kafka-template-receive

Comment: I tried by creating KafkaConsumer and polling the records by seeking beginOffset. But As KafkaConsumer is not-thread safe, I can run my search only one partition at a time. So for to complete 20 partitions its taking longer time. Please see my logic in Question (Option 2). How can achieve this in faster way. How to implement multithreading with KafkaConsumer ?

Comment: You cannot. `KafkaConsumer` is really intended for a single thread use only. Doesn't looks like what you are talking about is designed for Kafka as a store. Consider to have some DB in between. Kafka is messaging broker it cannot be searched a simple way per request.